# Any program which launches something whenever you type in a secret key combination?

Tags: windows

I'm looking for some program (free or paid) which just runs in the background (preferably hidden), and just keeps monitoring the keys you type .. and whenever it detects some specific key combination, it does something .. like run a script or a program, or launches some website or something ..

Anyone know of any such program ?

Comment: Do you need it to go undetected? What you're asking would require a keyboard hook, which should be detected by anti-malware programs.

Comment: I can add an exception if needed .. It would ne running on my own system, so its okay ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another program with the set of features you're after is [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Autohotkey has many automation features, amongst them is

> Create [hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for keyboard, joystick, and mouse. Virtually any key, button, or combination can become a hotkey.

You can specify any set of hotkeys that you like and then specify a script or command to run upon detection of that hotkey.

There's a brief set of tutorials [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).  But as an example if (after installing Autohotkey) you create a script (e.g. myScript.ahk) with the following

```
#n::
Run http://www.google.com
Run Notepad.exe
return
```

and run it you will get a little "A" in your system tray.  If you press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> it will run whatever program is associated to open URLs, then proceed to run notepad.

If you just want single hotkey to single command then

```
#n::Run Notepad
^!c::Run calc.exe
```

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> will run Notepad, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will run calc.exe

As you can see you can have a multitude of hotkeys in one script, ready to run whenever you like.

The turtorial and other [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/) is quite good, check it out.

-=EDIT=-

To answer your comment:

Generally I would expect the hotkeys to be a combination of keys to be pressed (and held) at the same time, the problem with typing "c h r o m e" is that you'll never be able to go to a website such as Superuser and ask a question about chrome without it coming up with a new window for your browser.

What you are after is doable though, using [hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) in Autohotkey.  typically these are used to expand abbreviations so (as in their example on the page I just linked) you can type "btw" and have it automatically replaced with it's full form of "by the way".

From [this documentation page](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) I would expect the following to do what you expect:

```
::chrome::Run chrome.exe
```

Though I would make the "chrome" something less likely to get typed in the normal course of using your computer, perhaps `chrme` or something, though that doesn't rule out spelling mistakes (of "charmed" or similar) annoying you.

To do this simply as a hotkey (all pressed at the same time) I would expect it to look like this:

```
chrome::Run chrome.exe
```

Note that a hotstring line begins with `::` while a hotkey line does not.

Comment: Sounds like what I need ...  So can I set the hotkey to be like this: c h r o m e   (i.e. 6 letters on the keyboard), and then set that to launch chrome ... Of course this is just an example and not what I actually want to do ..

Comment: Actually, just to clarify for myself, are you expecting to hold all these keys at the same time or to specifically type it one character at a time, the first is doable using the `hotkey` method, the second is via the `hotstring` method, I've detailed them both in my answer.

Comment: Although I haven't tried it out yet (life is busy - don't have time :/), but it sounds like its what I needed ... So I'm marking your answer .. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could hotkey customizations:
[Keyboard Launchpad](http://download.cnet.com/Keyboard-LaunchPad/3000-2094_4-10216877.html?part=dl-80664&subj=dl&tag=button)
Or something like a "bosskey" program and have the program in question already running and hidden.

Comment: So can I define something like when the user types in the following keys: c h r o m e .. its launches chrome for example ? .. This is what I'm looking for ... I am NOT looking for the traditional keyboard shortcuts like CTRL+ALT+C launches chrome or something ..

Comment: I think we need more details on your use case. If you'll be working at the command prompt you could just create batch or command files that launch the program you want and make sure they're in your path. Otherwise you'd need some kind of modified key logger and you'd be at risk of tripping the launcher when sending emails, writing letters etc. You'd need it to have some context sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign keys combination on desktop shortcuts. Create an application shortcut on desktop and right click on it, choose Properties. Then click Shortcut tab. There is a setting for shortcut key.

Comment: Nope that won't work .. The requirement is such that I need to type in a predefined word, which would launch something .. so for example if I defined 'chrome' to launch googl chrome, then typing in : c h r o m e .. would launch chrome ...

Comment: @Ahmad You mean like the search bar built into Windows 7? :)